# Keep certain Objects from scaling

Tags: wpf, animation, scaletransform

I have a WPF Canvas with a few objects on it and I apply a ScaleTransform animation to it (Zoom). As expected all objects scale with the canvas.

It is possible that some objects remain their size even if they are children of the canvas?

So far my only idea is another scale animation running in the opposite direction to scale to objects down again.

Comment: What about placing a 2nd canvas on top of the 1st one, with the non-scalable objects? The other alternative I can think of is a converter on the non-scalable objects which is bound to the scaled value and returns the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, no. the ScaleTransform will catch an element, and all it's children. You can only resort to tricks like you suggested.